# Reliably routing traffic to bare metal kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have started my own kubernetes cluster at home to learn kubernetes and I keep getting stuck when trying to expose my web services.
I have bootstrapped the cluster with k3s and everything is working nice, but I cannot figure out how I can robustly expose my webservices.
I have installed traefik 2.2 as an ingress controller and it is exposed via a loadbalancer service(I use the lb from k3s).

I have an A record that points to the global IP of one of the cluster nodes and I have portforwarded the ports that I want to expose, targeting this node.

I believe that I am not routing traffic to my loadbalancer in the correct way. Routing traffic to the loadbalancer service on one of my nodes works, but if I need to reboot the cluster for some reason the loadbalancer might end up on a different node and I have to change my target IP for the port forwarding. Setting the `externalIP` field of the loadbalancer service does not have any effect.

How do I reliably route traffic into my cluster? I feel like there is some part of the setup that I have misunderstood and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would like to use `ServiceType:` [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer):

> Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer.
> `NodePort` and `ClusterIP` Services, to which the external load
> balancer routes, are automatically created.

However, the service is hard to expose in a bare metal cluster since Kubernetes does not provide a load-balancer solution for bare metal environment.

The solution you could try is the [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/):

> MetalLB is a load-balancer implementation for bare metal Kubernetes
> clusters, using standard routing protocols.
>
> Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load-balancers
> (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare metal clusters. The
> implementations of Network LB that Kubernetes does ship with are all
> glue code that calls out to various IaaS platforms (GCP, AWS, Azure…).
> If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…),
> LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when
> created.

You can find the necessary details regarding installation, configuration and usage in the linked documentation. With it you should be able to setup your loadbalancing without too much trouble.

Comment: k3s includes a loadbalancer which actually gives the loadbalancer service an IP, but it keeps changing between reboots which makes it difficult to route traffic to if from my router. I am looking for a way I can route traffic that is a bit more deterministic.